# Using the Grails2 resource Plugin, how do I prevent escaping in the r:img tag when including arguments in javascript?

Tags: grails, gsp

This:

```
<r:img uri="${it.iconPath}" onclick="goOpenIt('${it.url}')"/>
```

becomes this:

```
<img src="/myapp/static/images/icon_32.png" onclick="goOpenIt(&#39;http://yahoo.com&#39;)" />
```

I want this:

```
<img src="/myapp/static/images/icon_32.png" onclick="goOpenIt('http://yahoo.com')" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't. For groovy tags every attribute's value is rendered with `encodeToHTML()`. Post answer if you find other solution for this.

Comment: I just verified in the source code of the resource tag lib that you are correct.

All attributes go through this method with no possibility of turning it off:
output << v.encodeAsHTML()

Answer (score 0):

After some additional research, I discovered that the following r:resource tag would fill the gap:

```
<img src="<r:resource uri="${it.iconPath}"/>" onclick="goOpenIt('${it.url}')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really

Look in your 
grails-app/conf/Config.groovy file for something like this...

grails.views.default.codec="none" // none, html, base64

If that is set to "html" then html will be escaped by default.